# using background task to update live tile with webservice data

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I was wondering its possible to run a method in my app from the Background task?, not just the code inside the background task. The reason im asking is that i have a Background task that i want to update my live tile with data from a webserive. I place the webservice calls inside the Background task as following:

```
public sealed class TileUpdater : IBackgroundTask
{
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient test = new ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient();
        var nb = await test.GetLatestDataAsync("temp");
        double temperature = nb.Value;
        string unit = nb.Unit;
        string latestTemp = " " + nb.Value + " " + nb.Unit;


        var defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
        updater.EnableNotificationQueue(true);

        updater.Clear();

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            var tile = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquareText02);
            tile.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].InnerText = "Tile " + latestTemp;
            tile.GetElementsByTagName("text")[1].InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm");

            updater.Update(new TileNotification(tile));
        }

        defferal.Complete();
    }
}
```

However when i run the app, nothing happens, and i dont get errors. It seems like it stops on the calling of the webservice. Is there anyway i can make the Background task call a method in the app code?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot to go on here, so I am taking a guess.  My suggestion - move the `GetDeferral` line to be first:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

    ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient test = new ServiceReference.WebServiceSoapClient();
    var nb = await test.GetLatestDataAsync("temp");
    double temperature = nb.Value;
    string unit = nb.Unit;
    string latestTemp = " " + nb.Value + " " + nb.Unit;

    // move up
    // var defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your background task in debugger to make sure no errors occur? There's a dropdown button in `Debug Location` toolbar next to `Process` combo box which you can use for that. Just start your app and then click on the name of your background task in the dropdown button.

[image]

Its `Run` method will start executing immediately and you'll be able to debug it just like your app code. I suppose the main reason you'd like to call an existing method in your app from the task is to be able to properly debug it.

You can find even more details on debugging tasks in [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj542415.aspx).